# 'sort' not working on a populated subcomponent in a Strapi v4 Service

Tags: javascript, strapi

I have working code inside a controller that pulls a populated component from a Singletype Element and sorts the elements of this component by one of its properties.
When i make this same code more flexible and move it to a service instead of the controller the code still works. I still get the populated component with sub components, but the sorting has no effect on the resulting array.

I have multiple controller actions in the form :

```
async destroyElement(ctx) {
    const { textelements } = await strapi
      .query("api::service.service")
      .findOne({
        populate: {
          textelements: { populate: ["pictures"], sort: ["order:asc"] },
        },
      }); .....
```

This works fine and results in "textelements" beeing an array sorted by the textelement property "order"
Since i have multiple such actions i intend to move the "Get all textelements" part out of the action itself and create a service function to do this.

```
async getTextelements(apiName, model) {
    const { textelements } = await strapi
      .query(`api::${apiName}.${model}`)
      .findOne({
        populate: {
          textelements: { populate: ["pictures"], sort: ["order:asc"] },
        },
      });
    // textelements.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
    return textelements;
  },
```

When i call this service function from the controller action the resulting array has the correct content but is not sorted by the "order" property.

I can ofcourse manually sort the array with the commented out function before returning it, but i would prefer to have this handled by the strapi query as the `sort: ["order:asc"]` should do, and did while the functionality was part of the controller action.

What am i missing here?